# USB device icon does not show up

Tags: gnome, usb, icons

I have a desktop machine that was recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. After the upgrade, nothing happens when I plug in a USB drive. No icons show up in the dock, and no icons show up in the Files explorer. The drives that are in my /etc/fstab have icons in both dock and files explorer.

I can mount USB drives just fine manually from a terminal. I have also tried creating a new user and logging in with it. In that session, plugging in a USB drive results in a nice pop-up and the requisite icons showing up where expected.

That obviously means that the problem is somewhere in the config for my user. Probably because it has carried over through several upgrades by now.

I have tried resetting everything available in dconf-editor, but that has not resolved the problem.

Does anybody know which dot-files might be the culprit here?